# arm-none-eabi-g++ ignoring invalid character `#' in expression stm32f4

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, embedded-linux, stm32f4discovery

I am constructing a makefile for the stm32f4 microconcroller that includes all the peripheral libraries and includes a syscalls (names newlib_stubs.cpp) of which redirects printf() to uart. before I start building all the sources into there own object file to be linked into an executable, I have written the makefile so that all sources are compiled in the one hit to prove that the makefile works at this stage but it doesn't work.
This is the makefile:

```
 #name of application
TARGET = main
#name of target outputs
TARGET_ELF = $(TARGET).elf
TARGET_BIN = $(TARGET).bin
TARGET_HEX = $(TARGET).hex


# directories
CODE_DIR = code/
LIBRARY_DIR = library/
BUILD_DIR = build/
SOURCE_DIR = $(CODE_DIR)src/
STARTUP_DIR = $(LIBRARY_DIR)startup/
LINKER_DIR = $(LIBRARY_DIR)linker/
PERIPHERAL_DIR = $(LIBRARY_DIR)peripherals/
DEFAULT_DIR = $(LIBRARY_DIR)default/
OUTPUT_DIR = $(BUILD_DIR)output/
OBJECT_DIR = $(BUILD_DIR)objects/
#SOURCE_MAIN_DIR = $(CODE_DIR)src/
SOURCE_LIBRARY_DIR = $(PERIPHERAL_DIR)src/
SOURCE_PERIPHERAL_DIR = $(DEFAULT_DIR)src/

# files with paths attached
_C_FILES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)*.c) # $(wildcard $(PERIPHERAL_DIR)src/*.c)
_C_DEFAULT_FILES = $(wildcard $(DEFAULT_DIR)src/*.c)
_C_PERIPHERAL_FILES = $(wildcard $(PERIPHERAL_DIR)src/*.c)
_CPP_FILES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)*.cpp) # $(wildcard $(PERIPHERAL_DIR)src/*.cpp)
_CPP_DEFAULT_FILES = $(wildcard $(DEFAULT_DIR)src/*.cpp)
_CPP_PERIPHERAL_FILES = $(wildcard $(PERIPHERAL_DIR)src/*.cpp)
_STA_FILES = $(wildcard $(STARTUP_DIR)*.s)
_SRC_FILES = $(_CPP_FILES) $(_C_FILES) $(_C_DEFAULT_FILES) $(_C_PERIPHERAL_FILES) $(_CPP_DEFAULT_FILES) $(_CPP_PERIPHERAL_FILES) $(_STA_FILES)
_OBJ_FILES = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR),$(notdir $(_CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)))
_OBJ_FILES += $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR),$(notdir $(_C_FILES:.c=.o)))
_OBJ_FILES += $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR),$(notdir $(_CPP_DEFAULT_FILES:.cpp=.o)))
_OBJ_FILES += $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR),$(notdir $(_C_DEFAULT_FILES:.c=.o)))
_OBJ_FILES += $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR),$(notdir $(_CPP_PERIPHERAL_FILES:.cpp=.o)))
_OBJ_FILES += $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR),$(notdir $(_C_PERIPHERAL_FILES:.c=.o)))
_OBJ_FILES += $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR),$(notdir $(_STA_FILES:.s=.o)))
_LNK_FILES = $(wildcard $(LINKER_DIR)*.ld)

#file names without paths
C_FILES = $(_C_FILES:$(SOURCE_DIR)%=%)
C_DEFAULT_FILES = $(_C_DEFAULT_FILES:$(DEFAULT_DIR)src/%=%)
C_PERIPHERAL_FILES = $(_C_PERIPHERAL_FILES:$(PERIPHERAL_DIR)src/%=%)
CPP_FILES = $(_CPP_FILES:$(SOURCE_DIR)%=%)
CPP_DEFAULT_FILES = $(_CPP_DEFAULT_FILES:$(DEFAULT_DIR)src/%=%)
CPP_PERIPHERAL_FILES = $(_CPP_PERIPHERAL_FILES:$(PERIPHERAL_DIR)src/%=%)
STA_FILES = $(_STA_FILES:$(STARTUP_DIR)%=%)
SRC_FILES = $(CPP_FILES) $(C_FILES) $(STA_FILES) $(C_DEFAULT_FILES) $(C_PERIPHERAL_FILES)
SRC_FILES += $(CPP_DEFAULT_FILES) $(CPP_PERIPHERAL_FILES)
OBJ_FILES = $(_OBJ_FILES:$(OBJECT_DIR)%=%)

#include directories
HEADERS = $(CODE_DIR)inc/
HEADERS += $(LIBRARY_DIR)default/inc/
HEADERS += $(LIBRARY_DIR)peripherals/inc/
HEADERS += 
HEADERS += 
HEADERS += 
HEADERS += 
HEADERS += 
HEADERS += 
HEADERS += 


LIB_PATH =





#libraries to link



# Tool configuration
TOOLCHAIN = arm-none-eabi-
CC = $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc
CXX = $(TOOLCHAIN)g++
AS = $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc
LD = $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc
OBJCOPY = $(TOOLCHAIN)objcopy

# Architecture configuration
ARCH_FLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 

# gcc compiler flags
CFLAGS += -O0 -ggdb3
CFLAGS += $(ARCH_FLAGS)
CFLAGS += -flto
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections
CFLAGS +=  -fdata-sections
CFLAGS += $(foreach i, $(HEADERS), -I$(i))

# g++ compiler flags
CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS += -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

# Flags for gcc as linker
LDFLAGS=$(ARCH_FLAGS)
LDFLAGS+=-Wl,--gc-sections
LDFLAGS+=$(foreach i, $(HEADERS), -L$(i))
LDFLAGS+=-T $(LDSCRIPT)









#.PHONY print

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(_SRC_FILES) -o $(TARGET_ELF)

print:
    @echo name of application:
    @echo TARGET = $(TARGET)
    @echo name of target outputs
    @echo TARGET_ELF = $(TARGET_ELF)
    @echo TARGET_BIN = $(TARGET_BIN)
    @echo TARGET_HEX = $(TARGET_HEX)
    @echo
    @echo directories
    @echo CODE_DIR = $(CODE_DIR)
    @echo LIBRARY_DIR = $(LIBRARY_DIR)
    @echo BUILD_DIR = $(BUILD_DIR)
    @echo SOURCE_DIR = $(SOURCE_DIR)
    @echo STARTUP_DIR = $(STARTUP_DIR)
    @echo LINKER_DIR = $(LINKER_DIR)
    @echo OUTPUT_DIR = $(OUTPUT_DIR)
    @echo OBJECT_DIR = $(OBJECT_DIR)
    @echo
    @echo files with paths attached:
    @echo _C_FILES = $(_C_FILES)
    @echo _C_DEFAULT_FILES = $(_C_DEFAULT_FILES)
    @echo _C_PERIPHERAL_FILES = $(_C_PERIPHERAL_FILES)
    @echo _CPP_FILES = $(_CPP_FILES)
    @echo _CPP_DEFAULT_FILES = $(_CPP_DEFAULT_FILES)
    @echo _CPP_PERIPHERAL_FILES = $(_CPP_PERIPHERAL_FILES)
    @echo _STA_FILES = $(_STA_FILES)
    @echo _SRC_FILES = $(_SRC_FILES)
    @echo _OBJ_FILES = $(_OBJ_FILES)
    @echo _LNK_FILES = $(_LNK_FILES)
    @echo
    @echo C_FILES = $(C_FILES)
    @echo C_DEFAULT_FILES = $(C_DEFAULT_FILES)
    @echo C_PERIPHERAL_FILES = $(C_PERIPHERAL_FILES)
    @echo CPP_FILES = $(CPP_FILES)
    @echo CPP_DEFAULT_FILES = $(CPP_DEFAULT_FILES)
    @echo CPP_PERIPHERAL_FILES = $(CPP_PERIPHERAL_FILES)
    @echo STA_FILES = $(STA_FILES)
    @echo SRC_FILES = $(SRC_FILES)
    @echo OBJ_FILES = $(OBJ_FILES)
```

The Source for this project can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32204435/stm324f-discovery_template_28Dec2013.zip

This is the output I receive from the compiler:

```
    nicholas@ASUS-G74Sx:~/Development/github/stm324f-discovery_template$ make
arm-none-eabi-g++ -O0 -ggdb3 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16  -flto -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -Icode/inc/  -Ilibrary/default/inc/  -Ilibrary/peripherals/inc/ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=c++11 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16  -Wl,--gc-sections  -Lcode/inc/  -Llibrary/default/inc/  -Llibrary/peripherals/inc/ -T  code/src/main.cpp    library/default/src/stm32f4_discovery.c library/peripherals/src/misc.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_adc.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_can.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_crc.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_cryp_aes.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_cryp.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_cryp_des.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_cryp_tdes.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_dac.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_dbgmcu.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_dcmi.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_dma.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_exti.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_flash.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_fsmc.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_gpio.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_hash.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_hash_md5.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_hash_sha1.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_i2c.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_iwdg.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_pwr.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_rcc.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_rng.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_rtc.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_sdio.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_spi.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_syscfg.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_tim.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_usart.c library/peripherals/src/stm32f4xx_wwdg.c library/default/src/newlib_stubs.cpp library/default/src/stm32f4xx_it.cpp library/default/src/system_stm32f4xx.cpp  library/startup/startup_stm32f4xx.s -o main.elf
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld:code/src/main.cpp:23: ignoring invalid character `#' in expression
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld:code/src/main.cpp:23: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
nicholas@ASUS-G74Sx:~/Development/github/stm324f-discovery_template$
```

main.cpp lines 0 to 30:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    main.c 
  * @author  MCD Application Team
  * @version V1.0.0
  * @date    18-April-2011
  * @brief   Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * THE PRESENT FIRMWARE WHICH IS FOR GUIDANCE ONLY AIMS AT PROVIDING CUSTOMERS
  * WITH CODING INFORMATION REGARDING THEIR PRODUCTS IN ORDER FOR THEM TO SAVE
  * TIME. AS A RESULT, STMICROELECTRONICS SHALL NOT BE HELD LIABLE FOR ANY
  * DIRECT, INDIRECT OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES WITH RESPECT TO ANY CLAIMS ARISING
  * FROM THE CONTENT OF SUCH FIRMWARE AND/OR THE USE MADE BY CUSTOMERS OF THE
  * CODING INFORMATION CONTAINED HEREIN IN CONNECTION WITH THEIR PRODUCTS.
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT 2011 STMicroelectronics</center></h2>
  ******************************************************************************  
  */ 

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_tim.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_syscfg.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_exti.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_dma.h"
#include "misc.h"
...
```

I can't identify any errors within the main.cpp file which is where they seem to be coming from.

What is casing this error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: The makefile doesn't help much! You should show the code at context from the compiler error.

Comment: Post your main.cpp from line 0 to at least 30, please. We need to see line 23.

Comment: Looks like the code you are trying to compile is written for an older version of compiler, which isn't quite so strict about the usage of for example `const char *` for passing to functions. I presume `_write` doesn't actually modify the string, so changing the second argument to `const char *` instead of `char *` should fix that particular issue.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: Line 23? Looks to me like lines 68 and 181? 
I also can't see what the relationship between the subject title and the actual error...???

Comment: @MatsPetersson Lines 68 and 181 throw warnings, but they don't prevent the compiler from continuing. The syntax error is thrown by the loader, 2 rows down.

Comment: Hm. The sytax error being reported by the loader means you're trying to feed a c source code to it instead of an object file. Maybe posting the Makefile wasn't that bad in the first place .. will look at it some more.

Comment: @MatsPetersson the warning generated by _write has been resolved by changing char * to const char *. That issue has been resolved but there is still the issue of that invalid character '#'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Makefile sets `LDFLAGS+=-T $(LDSCRIPT)` but doesn't define $LDSCRIPT. This results in `g++ -T {nothing here} main.cpp ...` being called, so the linker assumes main.cpp is the script. Try removing the `LDFLAGS+=-T $(LDSCRIPT)` from the Makefile.

Comment: This allows my application to compile. Also giving the linker a script to run is also helpful. I changed `LDFLAGS+=-T $(LDSCRIPT)` to `LDFLAGS+=-T $(LINKER_DIR)stm32_flash.ld`. This also compiled successfully.